# Git Revert a Revert for a Merge

Tags: git, github, merge, git-revert

I had a feature branch created, let's say `feature/branch1` on github.
I created a pull request for it and got it merged. 
[image: Initial PR Merge Commit]

When it reached our pipeline, we figured there was a problem and we got it reverted using the Revert button on Git
This created a "Revert" PR that we merged with the master and all was well.
[image: Reverted Merge Commit]

After a few weeks, post other PRs that got merged into the master, we figured we would *revert-the-revert*. This time, we went into the Revert PR that was closed and tried to use the Revert button again. But we got this error message

```
Sorry, this pull request couldn't be reverted automatically. 
It may have already been reverted, or the content may have changed since it was merged.
```

How do I get this revert done?

The most ideal situation I would like to have, is to have a new branch that contains the *revert of the revert*, so I can make further changes and go back through the PR process.

Comment: what tool did you use to revert? I seriously doubt git itself would print it

Comment: This `revert` button is a feature on github.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The error which you see is artificial check of github, which I personally find unneeded. You can revert the revert locally then:

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout origin/master (or reset)
git revert <REVERT HASH>
git push origin master
```

This should succeed, modulo conflicts with changes done since the revert.

PS: actually, the error could be because of the conflicts.

Comment: The error was indeed because of the conflicts. Although github does not really give much information.

Comment: if you encounter the error 'commit hash is a merge but no -m option was given' then you perform the revert on the original commit and not the commit created on merge of your revert PR.

Comment: What is original commit @shamanthGowdraShankaramurthy

Answer (score 4):

What you can try is:

- reset (`git reset --hard old_commit`) that PR branch to the commit you want to revert to (the one that was reverted)
- force push (`git push --force`) that branch: that will update the PR

That way, the PR is done again with the old commit.

> This is a merge commit. The PR is already closed and merged.

In that case, if you have fetch that old PR branch, you can do:

- a `git log` on it (`git log origin/old_pr_branch`)
- a new branch from the old SHA1 commit representing the content you now want

  ```
  git checkout -b new_pr_branch old_sha1
  ```
- a push to origin

  git push -u origin new_pr_branch

You can then make a new PR from that new branch, with the right content.

Comment: I would need more info here. This is a merge commit.
The PR is already closed and merged. I read it is not possible to re-open a closed PR. Am I reading your answer wrong?

Comment: @Serendipity I didn't get that the PR was closed. Do you still have access to the PR branch? The idea would be to make a new branch based on the old commit (the one that was reverted, but that you now want) and make a new PR from that new branch.

Comment: I have access to the PR branch, yes. However, the way I read your answer, it seems to update the existing PR branch

Comment: Ok, I ended up using a git gui and it showed some conflicts when the revert for the merge is done. I think this was the reason why the revert could not be completed properly. I fixed the conflicts and branched into a new branch.
I think the only problem with the method you've shown is that it is difficult to revert a merge commit unless you know which parent you want to revert into. I'll try this method you have mentioned and check.

Comment: "difficult to revert a merge commit unless you know which parent you want to revert into" that is what the git log will show you: the parent commits for you to chose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139956/discussion-between-serendipity-and-vonc).

Comment: This was cleaner solution for me compared to the accepted answer because it leads you directly to the situation in the original PR right before the revert has been made.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the command , initially you'd get this error
error 1: is a merge but no -m option was given.
error 2: option `mainline' expects a number greater than zero

This below command will fix it.
git revert -m 1 "commitId"